# Background color not changing from white

Tags: html, css, sass

For some reason the background color refuses to change from white. I am trying to get it to change from white to black under the header, but it refuses to change. Putting **"background-color:"** in the body SCSS doesn't seem to change it.

I am not sure if there is something in my SCSS that is simply over riding the background color without me realizing?

Any help is greatly appreciated

SCSS:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
background-color: '#010101';
}

#wrapperHeader {
width: 100vw;
height: 210px; /* height of the background image? */
background:url(images/header.png);
}

div#wrapperHeader div#header {
width: 100vw;
height:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}

div#wrapperHeader div#header img {
width: 100vw ; /* the width of the logo image */
height: 210px ; /* the height of the logo image */
margin:0 auto;
}

header {
color: white;
background-color: dimgrey ;
clear: left;
text-align: center;
}

.toggle_menu{
position: fixed;
padding: 17px 20px 15px 15px;
margin-top: 210px;
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #000;
z-index: 1000000;
font-size: 2em;
opacity: 0;

}

.sidebar_menu{
position: fixed;
width: 100vh;
max-width: 250px;
margin-left: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 100vh;
max-height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
opacity: 0,9;
transition: all 0.3s  ease-in-out;
}

.fa-times{
right: 10px;
top: 10px;
opacity: 0.7;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
color: red;
transition: all 0.3s  ease-in-out;

}

.fa-times:hover{
opacity: 1 ;
}

.boxed_item {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-weight: 200;
padding: 10px 20px;
display: inline-block;
border: solid 2px white;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-size: 22px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 70px;

}

.logo_bold{
font-weight: 800;
}

.logo_title{
color: white;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 0px;
}

.nav_selection{
margin: 0, 0;
display: block;
width: 200;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 5px;

}

.nav_item{
font-weight: 200;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
color: white;
padding: 15px 0;
font-size: 20px;
color: #D8D8D8;
border-bottom: solid 2px #D8D8D8;
transition: all 0.3s  ease-in-out;

}

.hide_menu{
margin-left: -250px;

}

.opacity_one{
opacity: 1;
}

.disabled {
pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
opacity:0.6; 

font-weight: 200;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
color: white;
padding: 15px 0;
font-size: 20px;
color: #D8D8D8;
border-bottom: solid 2px #D8D8D8;
transition: all 0.3s  ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Lot of code to be debugged.. anyways, specificity is the issue here, that's all I can say

Comment: Try setting the color without quotes: `background-color: #010101;`

Comment: @xs0 the part below the header is still white, not sure if setting up a container and setting that as black below the header would work?

Comment: try this background:#dddddd !important;

Comment: @GaneshPutta *"Using !important, however, is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets"*, by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: @GaneshPutta this changes the background colour, but also the header, and navbars color too and i need those to be a different color

Answer (score 3):

At three place you have give the background color code in three different style.
Please follow anyone format.

1. Never give the color in the quotation mark. You have given it in `*{ background-color: '#010101'; }` remember that. It should be `*{ background-color: #010101; }`.
2. You have given `background-color: dimgrey ;` so each time the color name is not working you have gave the color code for that.

This is header part for which you have to make change. for `dimgrey` the color code is: `#696969` so your code will be:

```
header {
color: white;
background-color: #696969; // check this line.
clear: left;
text-align: center;
}
```

It will make the change in the header parts background color. you have to check only that part.

3. It may be possible that other style will be override the background of header. In that case you have to put the `!important` in the code like this:

---

```
header {
color: white;
background-color: #696969 !important; // check this line.
clear: left;
text-align: center;
}
```

Let me know if it help you.

Comment: it changed the header color to the background color and the inside of the navbar too, however, the white space beneath it was still white, just seen your edit i'll update in two seconds

Comment: @AdamSteele can you share the screen shot of that. after making the changes?

Comment: i hope a gyazo is okay! https://gyazo.com/e5e6fcd8dc6f9503c8573ecc047180f8 i managed to include the code too

Comment: @AdamSteele yah I will be fine

Comment: @AdamSteele still facing the problem. let me know on which part you are facing issue

Comment: in the screenshot above the colors changed to my desired background color, im just trying to keep the same colors everywhere as in this screenshot but the massive white space changed to my desired background color https://gyazo.com/da7717e705405b93b89e875ae3ef9524 edit: i put ' in front of the background color in this to show you my desired look without it breaking, by removing the '' it changes my website back to the first screenshot

Comment: @AdamSteele for that you have to give same color code in your code. and white spaces are coming due to you have given the 
`border: solid 2px white;` in your code. change the color of it whatever you need. if after removing the  '  then remove that property.

Comment: the 'border: solid 2px white;' is only for the navbar title box, i tried removing it and making the changes but the giant white space below my header is still there and the colors of the navbar, and color of the header change to the color im trying to set for my background

Comment: @AdamSteele may be you have given the margin before or after that .. that's why the white space is showing. check your code.

Comment: i went through and checked my code and checked to see if i gace the margin elsewhere and its always set at 2px

Comment: @AdamSteele try after removing that. due to that it may be possible. Another thing that I show, you are using the image in header. so check your that image as well as it may be possible that there will be white space in image.

Answer (score 0):

Change background-color: '#010101'; this to 
background-color: '#010101!important';

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5638d70b57ee0f516fcf5e4488d5bc85 by doing this it changes the color of everything though, i tried adding the !important after all the other color declarations but that didn't work either

Comment: Oh! please give an id to what you want to change the color, then add it to css like : #name {
    background-color: #010101 !important;   
}
I think you have assigned the universal selector's background color as  #010101

Comment: all of the other things have ID's with the back ground color set, as seen in my SCSS above, it just seems to over ride all of them no matter what

Comment: *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
list-style: none;
background-color: '#010101';
}
This is overriding everything since you assigned it to universal selector *

Comment: so how would i go about making the background color not over ride literally everything so i can still keep my color scheme??

Comment: header {
color: white;
background-color: dimgrey !important ;
clear: left;
text-align: center;
}
Change your code like this